# how to execute command from Java application?

Tags: java, shell

How to execute Windows or Linux commands from a Java application?

I want to run `dir` command from Java application without a command prompt.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

well .. you could do it with

[`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

but you really don't want to ..

if you want to get a list of files in a directory use the File api!  something like [`file.listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just asked dir command i need to execute all type of commands like make directory and some mail server command etc can i use same Runtime class?

Comment: sure you can, just look at the linked api.. make sure to use the right methods.. so for example if you have multiple arguments make sure to pass a string array so you don't have to handle argument escaping yourself.. the returned Process class allows you to read the output / error stream from the started process, etc.

Answer (score 0):

probably you may need to read output of executed app as well, if you need that

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, `dir` is not an executable as such, but a command in the Windows command interpreter. To run `dir`, you would do Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C dir");